# Changing paths from webpack to firebase for deploy?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, webpack

Ive built a node app with webpack, running locally using `npm run start`. To deploy to firebase, I run `npm run build` which creates a public folder, then I deploy with `firebase deploy`.

Overall this works, but all my paths to supporting js files, images etc are screwed up. I get:

[image]

I can change the path on some to https://www.myfireabasedomain/the file path but I have many many references and this isnt realistic. How can I automatically change the paths for deployment? Maybe using config files or potentially `<base href=`?

my firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

my webpack.dev.js config:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './',
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    port: 9000
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
});
```

index.html looks like (the beginning):

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- <base href="https://deadends-d64b4.firebaseapp.com/" target="_blank"> -->

        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="./src/images/icon-192.png">
        <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./src/images//icon-32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./src/images/icon-16.png"> -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
        <meta name="description" content="Skylar's THREE js" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="webgl, threejs, repulsion, effect, hover, web development, demo, tutorial" />
        <meta name="author" content="Skylar Thomas" />
        <meta name="target" content="all">
        <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <title>DeadEnds</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sacramento|Montserrat:700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/zjs0dpp.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/99/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./src/scripts/vendor/shaders/FresnelShader.js"></script>
        <script src="./src/scripts/vendor/ParticleEngine.js"></script>
        <script src="./src/scripts/vendor/ParticleEngineExamples.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/scripts/vendor/CopyShader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/scripts/vendor/EffectComposer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/scripts/vendor/RenderPass.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/scripts/vendor/ShaderPass.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/scripts/vendor/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="./src/scripts/vendor/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.0/paper-core.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplex-noise/2.4.0/simplex-noise.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/3.1.0/parallax.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body oncontextmenu="return false;">
        <main>
              <!-- The cursor elements -->
        <div class="cursor cursor--small"></div>
```

webpack.common.js -

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      styles: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styles/'),
    }
  },
  // module: {
  //   rules: [
  //     {
  //       test: /\.js$/,
  //       exclude: /node_modules/,
  //       use: {
  //         loader: 'babel-loader'
  //       }
  //     }
  //   ]
  // },
  module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import']
                    }
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(glsl|frag|vert)$/,
                use: ['glslify-import-loader', 'raw-loader', 'glslify-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /three\/examples\/js/,
                use: 'imports-loader?THREE=three'
            },
            /*
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                use: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
                use: 'file-loader'
            }
            */
        ]
    },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
      }
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['public']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
  ]
};
```

Comment: what does you index.html file look like?

Comment: @MikeAbeln see the edit

Comment: Im not sure if theres enough information in there for me to help answer your question - can you add your `webpack.common.js` too? Might have something to do with your output path

Comment: @MikeAbeln see the edit again